# In Ant, how do I suppress the exec error "CreateProcess error=2"?

Tags: ant, exec

I'm attempting to execute a program, and if that fails I have a fallback method to get the information required.  Not everyone who uses this build script will have the program installed.  My task has the following:

```
<exec executable="runMe"
      failonerror="false"
      failifexecutionfails="false"
      outputproperty="my.answer"
      errorproperty="my.error"
      error="myerror.txt" />
```

Apparently I misunderstand the Ant manual because I thought by setting error or errorproperty the error would be redirected and not shown on the screen.

Is it possible to hide the message "Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "runMe"..."?

Alternately, is there a way to determine if that program can be run **without** checking for its existence?  If the program is on the user's system it won't be in the same place from user to user.

Thank you,

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal for doing this was to get the Subversion revision for my project in Ant.  Some developers have command line Subversion installed and others don't so I needed a way to test for the presence of svnversion.

In the end I used a batch file to test the command:

```
REM File checkCommand.bat
@echo off
%1 >NUL 2 >NUL
if errorlevel 1 goto fail

REM command succeeded 
exit 0

:fail
REM command failed
exit 1
```

In my Ant target I run this like so:

```
<target name="checkForSvnversion">
  <local name="cmdresult" />
  <exec dir="." executable="com"
        resultproperty="cmdresult"
        failonerror="false"
        failifexecutionfails="false">
      <arg line="/c checkCommand.bat svnversion" />
  </exec>

  <condition property="exec.failed">
    <equals arg1="${cmdresult}" arg2="1" trim="true" />
  </condition>
</target>
```

I have two targets that depend on this result:

```
<target name="getRevisionFromSvnversion" depends="checkForSvnversion"
        unless="exec.failed">
  etc etc
</target>
```

and

```
<target name="getRevisionFromEntries" depends="checkForSvnversion"
        if="exec.failed">
  etc etc
</target>
```

Finally, the task I call to get the revision is:

```
<target name="getRevision"
        depends="getRevisionFromSvnversion,getRevisionFromEntries">
  <echo>My rev is ${svn.revision}</echo>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try ant-contrib's try/catch/finally commands.

http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/trycatch.html

Comment: I didn't know about that. While I have a solution to the problem for now (posted as an answer) I'll try that once we finish this release. I'd like to be rid of the batch file I'm using.